# Angular 2 not loading data on page after the first visit

Tags: javascript, angular

I am having issue with data display, calling the intoFormat() function (with the 'relatedFunctions' sort, everything else seems to work correctly) displays the page correctly.  However, navigating away and back to that page results in the heading displaying the last digit of the function.id followed by a space and a null value for the subheading.  In addition the second time (only) visiting the page, the activities each load 9 separate times, but this error doesn't occur on subsequent .

The console gives no errors and stepping through the TS everything appears to match what it should.

Our lead dev suggested trying to implement Angular Async pipes but I would rather not make such a major change until I understand it more/ believe it would actually help.

Here is an Imgur gallery with screenshots of the three visits to the same page.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/49Bft.jpg

The HTML of the issue:

```
<div class="outer-card mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-grid" *ngFor="let activity of event.activities; let i = index">
<div *ngIf="intoIf(i)">
    <hr *ngIf="i > 0"/>
    <h4>{{intoFormat(activity, into).heading}} {{i}} {{intoFormat(activity, into).id}} <span
            *ngIf="intoFormat(activity, into).subheading">{{intoFormat(activity, into).subheading}}</span></h4>
</div>
```

and the Typescript:

```
 intoFormat(activity: any, sort: string) {
    let eventFun = this.event.functions;
    if (sort == 'relatedFunctions' && eventFun) {
        for (let fun of eventFun) {
            // console.log(fun.id);
            if (fun.id === activity[sort]) {
                // console.log(fun);
                return {
                    heading: fun.title,
                    subheading: `${fun.formattedStartTime} - ${fun.formattedEndTime}`,
                    id: fun.id
                };
            }
        }
    }
    if (sort == 'relatedTracks' && this.event.tracks) {
        for (let track of this.event.tracks) {
            if (track.id === activity[sort]) {
                return {
                    heading: track.title,
                    subheading: null
                };
            }
        }
    }
    if (sort == 'startDate' && this.event.tracks) {
        return {
            heading: activity['formattedStartTime'],
            subheading: activity['formattedStartDate']
        };
    }
    if (sort == 'formattedStartTime' && this.event.tracks) {
        return {
            heading: activity['formattedStartTime'],
            subheading: activity['formattedStartDate']
        };
    }
    if (sort == 'formattedStartDate' && this.event.tracks) {
        return {
            heading: activity['formattedStartDate'],
            subheading: null
        };
    }
    return {
        heading: activity[sort],
        subheading: null
    };
}
```

ngOnInit/ngOnChanges/constructor:

```
    constructor(protected eventService: EventService, protected router: Router, protected route: ActivatedRoute) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.parent.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.eventId = params['id'];
    });
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        if (!this.key) {
            this.key = decodeURIComponent(params['key']);
        }
        if (!this.filter) {
            this.filter = decodeURIComponent(params['val']);
        }
        if (!this.sort && params['sort']) {
            this.sort = decodeURIComponent(params['sort']);
        }
    });
    this.getEvent();
}

ngOnChanges() {
    this.getEvent();
}
```

The event data json mockup (can't show live data for contract reasons):

```
        "event": {
            "id": "~~~~766991",
            "title": "24th Annual Meeting Proceedings",
            "name": "datestsite",
            "modifiedDate": 1504713010000,
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras rutrum posuere justo, ut dignissim erat pellentesque sit amet. Fusce ac blandit ligula. In ligula velit, feugiat in mauris eget, consequat elementum odio. Pellentesque sodales purus ut diam auctor, in tempor enim porta. Vestibulum auctor dui ante, id gravida nunc ornare non. Cras consequat quam sed auctor lacinia. Mauris auctor, eros quis ultricies venenatis, turpis orci lacinia mi, sit amet finibus justo justo in elit. Nam vitae nisl non lorem auctor faucibus ac eu purus. In maximus ante libero, in euismod enim blandit sed. Duis convallis lectus at purus pellentesque vestibulum. Donec pulvinar erat justo, vel consectetur nunc dignissim nec. Curabitur vel lacus et quam condimentum pharetra at a nisl. Proin aliquam tincidunt mi, eu sollicitudin lacus venenatis et. Mauris tempus gravida purus interdum porttitor. Donec efficitur, magna sit amet tristique ornare, lacus quam suscipit arcu, ac suscipit enim est eget augue.",
            "timeZone": "America/New_York",
            "startDate": 1595649600764,
            "endDate": 1595736000764,
            "formattedStartDate": "July 25, 2020",
            "formattedStartTime": "12:00 AM",
            "formattedEndDate": "July 26, 2020",
            "formattedEndTime": "12:00 AM",
            "graphic": " ",
            "frontal": [
                {
                    "id": "~~~~767759",
                    "title": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
                    "name": "AMS 5 Steps",
                    "modifiedDate": 1504704844000,
                    "text": "",
                    "url": "/assets/attachments/Lorem.pdf",
                    "contentUrl": "http://lorem.com/",
                    "contentCategorization": "",
                    "displayPriority": "default"
                }
            ],
            "tracks": [
                {
                    "id": "~~~~767397",
                    "title": "Lorem",
                    "name": "CFO",
                    "modifiedDate": 1504647340000,
                    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras rutrum posuere justo, ut dignissim erat pellentesque sit amet. Fusce ac blandit ligula. In ligula velit, feugiat in mauris eget, consequat elementum odio. Pellentesque sodales purus ut diam auctor, in tempor enim porta. Vestibulum auctor dui ante, id gravida nunc ornare non. Cras consequat quam sed auctor lacinia. Mauris auctor, eros quis ultricies venenatis, turpis orci lacinia mi, sit amet finibus justo justo in elit. Nam vitae nisl non lorem auctor faucibus ac eu purus. In maximus ante libero, in euismod enim blandit sed. Duis convallis lectus at purus pellentesque vestibulum. Donec pulvinar erat justo, vel consectetur nunc dignissim nec. Curabitur vel lacus et quam condimentum pharetra at a nisl. Proin aliquam tincidunt mi, eu sollicitudin lacus venenatis et.",
                    "color": "#006699",
                    "graphic": ""
                }
            ]
            "functions": [
                {
                    "id": "~~~~767387",
                    "title": "Session 1",
                    "name": "f_001",
                    "description": " ",
                    "startDate": 1595684400000,
                    "endDate": 1595689200000,
                    "formattedStartDate": "July 25, 2020",
                    "formattedStartTime": "9:40 AM",
                    "formattedEndDate": "July 25, 2020",
                    "formattedEndTime": "11:00 AM",
                    "contentCategorization": ""
                }
            ],
            "activities": [
                {
                    "id": "~~~~767245",
                    "title": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
                    "name": "a_007",
                    "modifiedDate": 1504647201000,
                    "contentUrl": "http://lorem.com",
                    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
                    "startDate": 1595684400000,
                    "endDate": 1595689200000,
                    "formattedStartDate": "July 25, 2020",
                    "formattedStartTime": "9:40 AM",
                    "formattedEndDate": "July 25, 2020",
                    "formattedEndTime": "11:00 AM",
```

Comment: could you add the link for the gallery images you mentioned, and also how the `event` object looks like. If you can also show any component life-cycle hook methods (like ngOnInit, ngAfterViewInit etc and the constructor) that would be great to analyze the page initiation logic

Comment: Right before this line: `<div *ngIf="intoIf(i)">`, can you put in `<pre>{{ event.activities | json }}</pre>` to see if the data is loaded, or if it's a problem elsewhere.

Comment: Can you demonstrate the issue through plunker?

Comment: The Imgur gallery is actually there now as well as the ngOnInit and ngOnChanges.    
@Phix I put that code before and it loads correctly the first time and loads the second time, but loads a full copy 9 times and manages to freeze the app